# Is this use of 「こみ」 instead of 「ごみ」 in 「ごみ収集ステーション」 accidental or a variation?

Tags: orthography, dialects

In [this question on the Travel SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/103754/53124) OP is asking about こみ収集ステーション that he has seen, and provided this image of a notice on one of those from Higashidori, Aomori:

[image]

The pic is blurry, but not so bad that a missing 濁点 could be attributed to the quality of the pic. Why is it 「こみ」 instead of 「ごみ」 here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've [found a box that shows the dakuten](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@41.1332027,141.3908915,3a,15y,102.99h,89.52t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sBsvu7wkLKYPh05rpJtOQRA!2e0!7i13312!8i6656?hl=en), it's barely visible but it's there.

[image]

To confirm this, I did a bit of digging around and double checked on the [Higashidori government website](http://www.vill.higashidoori.lg.jp/sub02/cat200037.html) where it uses 'ごみの収集'.

Answer (score 5):

It's likely a typographical error, or the 濁点 is incredibly illegible in the image. こみ収集 doesn't make sense enough that my keyboard auto-corrects to katakana (doesn't make sense either).

Comment: I've just found a [box that shows the dakuten](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@41.1332027,141.3908915,3a,15y,102.99h,89.52t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sBsvu7wkLKYPh05rpJtOQRA!2e0!7i13312!8i6656?hl=en), it's barely visible but it's there.

Comment: Nice sleuthing.

Comment: @Ambo100 post that as an answer! (With an example image)

Answer (score 0):

Either blurred or a typo. It's definitely ごみ